# Floating Action Button Oval not changing

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, floating-action-button

I'm trying to implement code for a Floating Action Button, but for some reason the oval is not replacing the current button.

**activity_upcoming.xml:**

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/add_button"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/diameter"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/diameter"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Upcoming"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/Upcoming"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/add_button_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/add_button_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
    android:tint="@android:color/white"
    android:shape="@drawable/oval_ripple"
    android:elevation="@dimen/elevation_low"
    android:stateListAnimator="@anim/button_elevation"
    />
```

**oval_ripple.xml:**

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
  <item>
      <shape android:shape="oval">
          <solid android:color="#095578" />
      </shape>
  </item>
</ripple>
```

**Upcoming.java:**

```
public class Upcoming extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upcoming);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crime_list, parent, false);
        } else {
            v = super.onCreateView(inflater, parent, savedInstanceState);
        }
        int diameter = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.diameter);
        Outline outline = new Outline();
        outline.setOval(0, 0, diameter, diameter);
        View addButton = v.findViewById(R.id.add_button);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_upcoming, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();


        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The button continues to stay rectangle shaped, and the colour does not change. I've verified the ripple code with several websites to no avail.

Comment: There is no `android:shape` attribute on `ImageButton`. Perhaps you meant `android:background`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
<ImageButton
...
android:shape="@drawable/oval_ripple"
/>
```

To

```
<ImageButton
...
android:background="@drawable/oval_ripple"
/>
```

Also ripple code require minSDKVersion = 21 so make sure you have done it correctly.

Comment: Thank you. The background has changed into an oval shape. Unfortunately the shadow is still square.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking at this git in Github: https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton

You can create floating action buttons with no problem with this library and it has very good documentation. Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of simple libraries that you can use for this purpose rather than creating your own button. Each has its own set of features which you can use. 
The advantage of using these is that it allows you to easily replicate the ripple effect and add other animations as well .
Check out this link :

https://android-arsenal.com/tag/173

Cheers !